# implementing ease in update loop

Tags: objective-c, easing

I want to animate a sprite from point y1 to point y2 with some sort of deceleration. when it reaches point y2, the speed of the object will be 0 so it will completely stop.

I Know the two points, and I know the object's starting speed.
The animation time is not so important to me. I can decide on it if needed.

for example: `y1 = 0`, `y2 = 400`, `v0 = 250` pixels per second (= starting speed)

I read about easing functions but I didn't understand how do I actually implement it in the 
update loop.
here's my update loop code with the place that should somehow implement an easing function.

```
-(void)onTimerTick{
   double currentTime =  CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() ;
   float timeDelta = self.lastUpdateTime - currentTime;
   self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

   float *pixelsToMove = ???? // here needs to be some formula using v0, timeDelta, y2, y1

   sprite.y +=  pixelsToMove;
}
```

Comment: Why, why, why don't you use Core Animation for this? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: because, because, because I'm doing other actions and validations in this update loop.

Comment: I don't know if that was a valid argument or if I just felt like explaining Bézier curves :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Timing functions as Bézier curves

An easing timing function is basically a Bézier curve from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` where the horizontal axis is "time" and the vertical axis is "amount of change". Since a Bézier curve mathematically is as

```
start*(1-t)^3 + c1*t(1-t)^2 + c2*t^2(1-t) + end*t^3
```

you can insert any time value and get the amount of change that should be applied. Note that both time and change is normalized (in the range of 0 to 1).

**Note** that the variable t is *not* the time value, t is how far along the curve you have come. *The time value is the x value of the point along the curve*.

---

The curve below is a sample "ease" curve that starts off slow, goes faster and slows down in the end.

If for example a third of the time had passed you would calculate what amount of change that corresponds to be update the value of the animated property as

```
currentValue = beginValue + amountOfChange*(endValue-beginValue)
```

[image: Bézier curve for "ease" timing function]

## Example

Say you are animating the position from `(50, 50)` to `(200, 150)` using a curve with control points at `(0.6, 0.0)` and `(0.5, 0.9)` and a duration of 4 seconds (the control points are trying to be close to that of the image above).

When 1 second of the animation has passed (25% of total duration) the value *along* the curve is:

```
(0.25,y) = (0,0)*(1-t)^3 + (0.6,0)*t(1-t)^2 + (0.5,0.9)*t^2(1-t) + (1,1)*t^3
```

This means that we can calculate `t` as:

```
0.25 = 0.6*t(1-t)^2 + 0.5*t^2(1-t) + t^3
```

[Wolfram Alpha tells me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.25+%3D+.6*t%281-t%29%5E2+%2B+.5*t%5E2%281-t%29+%2B+t%5E3) that `t = 0.482359`

If we the input that `t` in

```
y = 0.9*t^2*(1-t) + t^3
```

we will get the "amount of change" for when 1 second of the duration has passed.

Once again [Wolfram Alpha tells me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+0.9*t%5E2*%281-t%29+%2B+t%5E3%2C+t%3D0.482359) that `y = 0.220626` which means that 22% of the value has changed after 25% of the time. This is because the curve starts out slow (you can see in the image that it is mostly flat in the beginning).

So finally: 1 second into the animation the position is

```
(x, y) = (50, 50) + 0.220626 * (200-50, 150-50)
(x, y) = (50, 50) + 0.220626 * (150, 100)
(x, y) = (50, 50) + (33.0939, 22.0626)
(x, y) = (50+33.0939, 50+22.0626)
(x, y) = (83.0939, 72.0626)
```

I hope this example helps you understanding how to use timing functions.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation :)  I understand the concept now, but practically - I need to calculate the "amount of Change" using the bezier points (c1,c2) and the elapsed time (x). for this, I need to replace the 't' varaiable with an expression that consists of c1,c2,x. I couldn't figure out how to do it, because it's a complex equation.

Comment: That is why I strongly suggested to let Core Animation handle it. If you know the control points beforehand you can calculate t = f(x) and it won't be *too* hard. If you need to change c1 and c2 at runtime you can still get [some help from WolframAlpha by changing all constants to variables](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c+%3D+a*t%281-t%29%5E2+%2B+b*t%5E2%281-t%29+%2B+t%5E3) but it won't be easy

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what 't' is in your formula. however, I succeeded to implement ease functions like these: http://www.gizma.com/easing/  . they return the value I need.  but as I wrote at the begnning, I want to control the starting speed, so I need to adjust manually (by feel) the duration to get the desired starting speed. or is there another way?

Comment: Your start speed is the number if pixels per second, right? That is what the angle from the start point to the first control point describes. If the angle is 0 the start speed is zero. Of the angle is very steep the start speed is very fast. Just divide the absolute start speed by the total change to normalize it.

Comment: I have a doubt, why is t not the time as it moves uniformly over period of [0,1]?

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly, (time, progress) is a point on a cubic Bezier curve. Both time and progress are functions of parameter t in [0,1]. And currentValue = startValue*(1-progress) + endValue*progress. So given time value, we need to find corresponding progress value and then using found progress value, find currentValue. Am I correct?