# Solving Bezier curve

Tags: c#, bezier

I am writing a code for a motion controller for cameras, the bezier curve equation is used to make the motion smooth.

As my math abilities are not so strong, i used the code found on this "stackoverflow" answer [Interpolating values between interval, interpolation as per Bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883264/interpolating-values-between-interval-interpolation-as-per-bezier-curve/38236671#38236671)  , thanks to the member "Daniel Wolf".

```
using System;
public class Point {
public Point(double x, double y) 
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
public double X { get; private set; }
public double Y { get; private set; }
}

public class BezierCurve {
public BezierCurve(Point p0, Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    P0 = p0;
    P1 = p1;
    P2 = p2;
    P3 = p3;
}

public Point P0 { get; private set; }
public Point P1 { get; private set; }
public Point P2 { get; private set; }
public Point P3 { get; private set; }

public double? GetY(double x) {
    // Determine t
    double t;
    if (x == P0.X) {
        // Handle corner cases explicitly to prevent rounding errors
        t = 0;
    } else if (x == P3.X) {
        t = 1;
    } else {
        // Calculate t
        double a = -P0.X + 3 * P1.X - 3 * P2.X + P3.X;
        double b = 3 * P0.X - 6 * P1.X + 3 * P2.X;
        double c = -3 * P0.X + 3 * P1.X;
        double d = P0.X - x;
        double? tTemp = SolveCubic(a, b, c, d);
        if (tTemp == null) return null;
        t = tTemp.Value;
    }

    // Calculate y from t
    return Cubed(1 - t) * P0.Y
        + 3 * t * Squared(1 - t) * P1.Y
        + 3 * Squared(t) * (1 - t) * P2.Y
        + Cubed(t) * P3.Y;
}

// Solves the equation ax³+bx²+cx+d = 0 for x ϵ ℝ
// and returns the first result in [0, 1] or null.
private static double? SolveCubic(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    if (a == 0) return SolveQuadratic(b, c, d);
    if (d == 0) return 0;

    b /= a;
    c /= a;
    d /= a;
    double q = (3.0 * c - Squared(b)) / 9.0;
    double r = (-27.0 * d + b * (9.0 * c - 2.0 * Squared(b))) / 54.0;
    double disc = Cubed(q) + Squared(r);
    double term1 = b / 3.0;

    if (disc > 0) {
        double s = r + Math.Sqrt(disc);
        s = (s < 0) ? -CubicRoot(-s) : CubicRoot(s);
        double t = r - Math.Sqrt(disc);
        t = (t < 0) ? -CubicRoot(-t) : CubicRoot(t);

        double result = -term1 + s + t;
        if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;
    } else if (disc == 0) {
        double r13 = (r < 0) ? -CubicRoot(-r) : CubicRoot(r);

        double result = -term1 + 2.0 * r13;
        if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;

        result = -(r13 + term1);
        if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;
    } else {
        q = -q;
        double dum1 = q * q * q;
        dum1 = Math.Acos(r / Math.Sqrt(dum1));
        double r13 = 2.0 * Math.Sqrt(q);

        double result = -term1 + r13 * Math.Cos(dum1 / 3.0);
        if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;

        result = -term1 + r13 * Math.Cos((dum1 + 2.0 * Math.PI) / 3.0);
        if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;

        result = -term1 + r13 * Math.Cos((dum1 + 4.0 * Math.PI) / 3.0);
        if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;
    }

    return null;
}

// Solves the equation ax² + bx + c = 0 for x ϵ ℝ
// and returns the first result in [0, 1] or null.
private static double? SolveQuadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
    double result = (-b + Math.Sqrt(Squared(b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;

    result = (-b - Math.Sqrt(Squared(b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    if (result >= 0 && result <= 1) return result;

    return null;
}

private static double Squared(double f) { return f * f; }

private static double Cubed(double f) { return f * f * f; }

private static double CubicRoot(double f) { return Math.Pow(f, 1.0 / 3.0); }
}
```

The code wrote by Daniel works very well with relatively small values (less than 1000), but when i try to use it with higher values (more than 1000), the function gives no values.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Problem solved

Comment: If you solved the problem, please either post an answer is you think this problem is one others will run into as well, or delete your post so people looking for an answer to their problem won't run into it in the future only to discover there "is" a solution, but no one bothered to say what it was. Given that this question has upvotes, writing the solution instead of deleting is probably the right way to go.